# Executing same stored procedure parallel from c# using Tasks using multiple connection not giving good response time

Tags: c#, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure which invokes a R prediction model based on the input params. I need to execute this SP parallelly because a single request to my C# service will contain a list of params and for each if i invoke the SP it is going to take long time to complete.

I use the below code

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(var req in request)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async() =>
              await _repository.GetVolumePrediction(
                                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req), tenantCode),
                                TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

GetVoulumePrediction

```
public async Task<double> GetVolumePrediction(string jsonInput, string tenantCode)
{
    using (var connection = ConnectionFactory.GetConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        _logger.Debug(this, "Conn opened");
        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand() as SqlCommand;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@TenantCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10)
                          .Value = tenantCode;
        command.Parameters.Add("@jsonPredictionRequest", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1)
                          .Value = jsonInput;
        command.CommandTimeout = 0;
        command.CommandText = "PredictVolume_MulWeek_MulAccountSku_New2";
        predictedVolume = Convert.ToDouble(await command.ExecuteScalarAsync());
        _logger.Debug(this, predictedVolume.ToString());
    }
}
```

If one execution takes say 2 second, if i start 10 tasks currently it is taking more than 20 seconds to complete, its not giving the effect of parallel execution. My expectation is to get the result in 2-4 seconds.

Comment: The problem is that by using `Task.Factory.StartNew` you are spinning up CPU-bound thread pool threads only to perform blocking I/O calls to a database.  That won't scale and you will run out of threads quickly.  Better to use `await` on a **new**  `GetVolumePredictionAsync` method that makes calls to `async` Sql.   Use `async` all the way for IOCP.  https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html.  Eventually you will run into whatever limits are on SQL's max concurrency

Comment: Questions about paralleling database queries because they are slow are a sure sign your database queries and indexes needs optimizing. If your DB is maxing out because of a bad query why would it not makes sense throwing more threads at it scales linearly . as noted IO workloads should use the async await pattern, however this is probably not going to give you much. I think you need to head to the DB stackexchange and work out your problems first

Comment: I have updated the code using async as you suggested, but no luck. Please check the updated code and suggest anything wrong.

Comment: SQL Server already knows how to parallelize queries. Those 2 seconds are mostly likely with the procedure using all cores available on the server. Trying to speed things up by giving the same cores more work to do isn't going to work. (If it does nothing but invoke R, then there might be some room for improvement, depending on what exactly is going on -- but here too it would not surprise me if the available parallelism is already fully exploited.) To verify if this is the problem, try just executing the procedure multiple times from different Management Studio tabs.

Comment: Maybe your issue is with the work associated to the number of worker threads you have available to the model.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/administration/modify-user-account-pool?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Hi Neil, i have tried most of the optimization option for machine learning in sql server. I have a limitation of CPU and  memory, am trying this is 2 core machine with 6GB Ram. My scripts are failing due to resource limitation - is there any way to try this parallel processed with this limited resource. I will have a server commissioned shortly with more resources.